# What is wrong with this validation formula, it lets users to just input in one field instead I need them to put value in all fields

Tags: picklist, validation-rule

```
AND(
  OR(
    ISPICKVAL( Why_lost__c , "Better competitive solution"),
    ISPICKVAL( Why_lost__c ,"missing features"),
    ISPICKVAL( Why_lost__c , "Competitor")),
    ISPICKVAL( StageName , "Closed Lost"),
    ISBLANK( What_features_did_you_need__c ),
    ISBLANK( Other_vendor_technology_intended__c ),
    ISBLANK(What_would_have_prevented_from_Churn__c) 
  )
)
```

Comment: looks like missing opening bracket before OR?

Comment: Yes, Now I correctly edited

Comment: I have added one opening bracket before OR and later when OR closes but still no vail. same problem. Users are not compelled to put values in intended 3 fields but just one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of AND and OR is incorrect. It should look like:

```
AND(
  OR(
    ISPICKVAL( Why_lost__c , "Better competitive solution"),
    ISPICKVAL( Why_lost__c ,"missing features"),
    ISPICKVAL( Why_lost__c , "Competitor")
  ),
   ISPICKVAL( StageName , "Closed Lost"),
  OR(
    ISBLANK( What_features_did_you_need__c ),
    ISBLANK( Other_vendor_technology_intended__c ),
    ISBLANK(What_would_have_prevented_from_Churn__c) 
  )
)
```

Note that, from a UX perspective, this should be three validation rules, so you can attach an error message to each separate field, making it easier for users to know which fields are required.

Comment: Thanks Sfdcfox, can you let me know if it won´t let users to just fill out one of the last OR fields, my requirement is that all the fields in last OR statements of your correction should be filled by user if picklist values are one of the above.

Comment: I now need to understand how AND and OR work together, nice that helped. Thanks